# List view Not Displaying Data

Tags: android, listview

so recently i had an issue that i could not get more than one record to display from a online database in my android app. I was using text view but was advised to utilize a list view. With the help of some kind people on here i have been pointed in the right direction how ever i am still having trouble as the list view does not display anything.  I will attach the code below which i have annotated for this post.

For reference i am utilising volley and php, when accessing the data through the url, example: http://example.url/data.php/$id=1

```
public class GetExerciseList extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


private EditText editTextId;
private Button buttonGet;
private TextView textViewResult;
ListView listView ;
ArrayAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
private ProgressDialog loading;
```

INITIALIZING VIEWS

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_getexerciselist);

    editTextId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
    buttonGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);
    textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dataList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    buttonGet.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

DECLARING ADAPTERS AND VIEWS

```
private void getData() {
    String id = editTextId.getText().toString().trim();
    if (id.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter an id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);
    String url = Config.DATA_URL+editTextId.getText().toString().trim();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            showJSON(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {                       Toast.makeText(GetExerciseList.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

FETCHING DATA BASED ON MATCHING ID

```
private void showJSON(String response){
    String musclegroup="";
    String exercise="";

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject collegeData;
       for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++) {
            collegeData = result.getJSONObject(i);
            musclegroup = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_MUSCLEGROUP);
            exercise = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_EXERCISE);

           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           dataList.add(musclegroup + " " + exercise + " ");
       }
```

FOR LOOP TO LOOP THROUGH JSON DATA, AND ADD ALL RECORDS TO THE DATALIST

```
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

EXCEPTION CATCHER

```
   textViewResult.setText("Target Muscle:\t" + musclegroup + "\nLift:\t" + exercise);
  //  this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dataList));

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dataList);

}
```

TEXTVIEW LEFT IN JUST TO CHECK DATA. LIST VIEW CURRENTLY HAS NO OUTPUT
LISTVIEW ADAPTER DECLARED AND SET, DATA SET AS "datalist"

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    getData();
}
}
```

I have broken this down to make this easily readable, thank you everyone for the help as always it is very appreciated.

Comment: interchange 
 `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
  `dataList.add(musclegroup + " " + exercise + " ");`
first add in `arraylist` and than notify adapter

Comment: Are u getting response? Did u check that dataList arraylist has data. What is the size of it?

Comment: Hey, i managed to get it to display, how ever i now am back to the issue of it only displaying 1 record, when it should display more than one

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add the datas and notify the adatper.

```
private void showJSON(String response){
    String musclegroup="";
    String exercise="";
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject collegeData;
       for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++) {
            collegeData = result.getJSONObject(i);
            musclegroup = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_MUSCLEGROUP);
            exercise = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_EXERCISE);
           dataList.add(musclegroup + " " + exercise + " ");
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

       }
```

Comment: Changes applied. Still receiving no list view output. Thank you for help

Comment: I now have managed to produce an output, but it is not displaying more than one record

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is to create your adapter and set it to the `ListView` after the loop is finished instead to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` every time in the loop until iterate your response.

```
private void showJSON(String response){
    String musclegroup="";
    String exercise="";
   try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject collegeData;
        for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++) {
            collegeData = result.getJSONObject(i);
            musclegroup = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_MUSCLEGROUP);
            exercise = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_EXERCISE);
           dataList.add(musclegroup + " " + exercise + " ");
       }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dataList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this does appear more refined, how ever even with the code iterating through notifydatasetchanged. I am still receiving no output from the list view. I can only see the textview on screen

Comment: May be you haven't response data, but exception occured. Did you check that?

Comment: I have now managed to get the list view displaying. Only issue is i can only see 1 record, Not sure what my issue is, the list view seems fine now, issue is with my java loop somewhere

Comment: hm... try to log your JSONArray length: `Log.d("JSONArray length ",result.length() + "");` and let me know how it is.

Comment: It is coming back as "length 1". When it should be 3 records that match

Comment: It seems everything is good, the problem is in your response, but if you have array with length == 1 it is normal to see only one row in the listview

Comment: Yes, the list view seems fine. The issue is definitely with pushing the response through. The array length should be 3. As there are 3 records with a matching id of 1. But it is only retrieving 1. Any ideas on how to remedy this? Thank you